# How to add a "current" class to a single javascript file that acts as a navigation bar, hosted on a local network (no SSI/PHP).

Tags: javascript

I'm hosting a Local area website with a number of pages, using javascript to load a single file navigation bar.
A shortened version (most links removed) of my javascript file looks like this:

Javscript file navigation.js:

```
var lnk = ' ';
lnk+='<br>';
lnk+='<ul id="navigationlinks">Available Pages:';
lnk+='<li><a href="../customerpages/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>';
lnk+='<li><a href="../customerpages/page2.html">Page 2</a></li>';
lnk+='<li><a href="../customerpages/page3.html">Page 3</a></li>';
lnk+='</ul>';
document.write(lnk);
```

The HTML code I use to load the navigation menu is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/navigation.js"></script>
```

Currently the page loads and all links work. 
I have a CSS stylesheet listing "current" class to highlight any anchors yellow, and if I manually add the class (a class="current") it works. 
however I'd like to have this class automatically added automatically.

I played with some jquery/scripts and I can get the class to add automatically to my menu if I have the unordered list put directly in the HTML, however I can not figure out how to add this to the list held in the navigation.js file. 
What may be the easiest way to simply add class="current" to my navigation.js file?

Comment: Ew, `document.write`; whyfor? How are you trying to add the CSS originally, onDomReady, or...?

Comment: Only using it because I have know prior practice/knowledge using javascript and it works. I found an example of a working setup on another forum, changed it to match mine and it does what I need. I would love an alternate/simpler method - my main goal is to have a single file that can be easily updated/changed for the navigation of the site without having to modify html on all pages.